# PHP mobile emulator program

Tags: php

I am working on project on page i have a big image of mobile. There is top input box which is looking for any site url.If somebody is any website url theta website output will be display in mobile interface. I am using

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is waaaaay too broad a question. Ask something specific - we're not here to design an entire site/system for you.

Comment: You're still not asking a relevant question. You're trying to do open heart surgery before you've learned to apply a bandaid

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting with PHP, I would not suggest trying to create something so complex.

The site you link to is very complex and a lot of it is done client side in Javascript.

Try some easier projects first to get familiar with PHP and Javascript before you try something so complex.

Comment: I am not fully i know much more about php, javascript and Ajax. Ad also please see my question i have edited it. Thanks